# Program that keeps running until user types a word

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

Generate a random number between 1 and 9 (including 1 and 9). Ask the user to guess the number, then tell them whether they guessed too low, too high, or exactly right. (_Hint: remember to use the user input lessons from the very first exercise

Extras:

Keep the game going until the user types “exit”
Keep track of how many guesses the user has taken, and when the game ends, print this out.

I have divided my program in three functions

```
import random

# function to generate random number between 1 and 9
def generate():
    cpu_number=random.randint(1,9)
    print(cpu_number)

# function to input player guess
def player_guess():
    player_number=input('Digit a number between 1 and 9\n')

#function to keep asking the player the value unless he writes exit. Also return wrong and right guesses
def game():
    right_guesses=0
    wrong_guesses=0
    while player_guess()!= 'exit':
        if player_guess() > generate():
            print('Higher value than the value generated!')
            wrong_guesses += 1
        elif player_guess() < generate():
            print('Lower value than the value generated!')
            wrong_guesses += 1
        else:
            print('You have guessed the correct value!!!!')
            right_guesses += 1
    print('You have entered',right_guesses,'guesses and',wrong_guesses,'guesses')
    return right_guesses,wrong_guesses

print(generate())
print(player_guess())
print(game())
```

My program is not running the if sentences. Also it does not stop if i type exit

Comment: `player_guess()` does not _return_ a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random

# function to generate random number between 1 and 9
def generate():
    return random.randint(1,9)

# function to input player guess
def player_guess():
    return input('Digit a number between 1 and 9\n')


#function to keep asking the player the value unless he writes exit. Also return wrong and right guesses
def game():
    right_guesses=0
    wrong_guesses=0
    while True:
        guess = player_guess()
        if guess == 'exit':
            break

        if int(guess) > generate():
           print('Higher value than the value generated!')
           wrong_guesses += 1
        elif int(guess) < generate():
            print('Lower value than the value generated!')
            wrong_guesses += 1
        else:
            print('You have guessed the correct value!!!!')
            right_guesses += 1

    print('You have entered', right_guesses,'correct guesses and', wrong_guesses,'wrong guesses')
    return right_guesses, wrong_guesses

game()
```

Comment: Why cant i say  while player_guess()!='exit'      and another thing why do you say guess=player guess() two times ?

Comment: i have a code similar to yours and it runs an endeless loop

Comment: the only thing i did diferent was that i wrote guess = player_guess() before the while loop

Comment: but imagine. If i store and call my functions in variables before de while why does the program runs endeless prints ?

Answer (score 1):

`player_guess` doesn't return anything for the loop in `game` to react to.  Also, it appears to be called more often than once per desired input.

Comment: what you sugest i should do?